# Configuring container-managed security in Weblogic

Tags: security, weblogic

Anyone know of any guides for this? I'm a complete newbie to weblogic and to container-managed security. What I've done already is:

1. setup an LDAP authenticator in Weblogic
2. created a simple webapp in Eclipse
3. Configure web.xml: Added security-constraint, security-role and login-config elements. The realm name used is "myrealm" which already exists in Weblogic. The role name I used is "Admin" which is a global role in Weblogic
4. Create a simple jsp page "login.jsp". It doesn't actually do any logging in but just a Hello World type of thing. I set this page as form-login-page and form-error-page in login-config in web.xml
5. Export this webapp to a war file and deploy it in Weblogic
6. I test it by accessing http://weblogic-server/test/login.jsp, and I expect that I'll be asked to login using an LDAP user first. This doesn't happen, it just shows the Hello World jsp.

I've also tried adding a weblogic.xml to map the "Admin" role to a specific LDAP user (didn't work).

Any advice? It seems there's a lack of online references for this sort of thing (or I don't really know what I should be searching for)

Edit: I've also tried using BASIC auth instead of FORM (no luck)

My web.xml settings are below:

```
<security-constraint>
<display-name>Test SC</display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Test WR</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello.jsp</url-pattern>
    <http-method>*</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
<role-name>Admin</role-name>
</security-role>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page must do some sort of logging in, with the 2 required fields. You have protect the hello_world.jsp page in the web.xml and go to that pages, the login page will be presented.

Edit:
The order is incorrect: it should be `security-constraint`, `login-config` and `security-role`.
Within the `web-resource-collection` the value of `*` is invalid for `http-method`. If you want to protect every method just leave it away.

Note: the server logging whould have hinted the incorrect order of elements in your web.xml.

Comment: I've tried this, but I'm still getting the hello world page and not getting the login page. I haven't implemented the logging in, I just want to see the redirect to the login page first =/

Comment: then your security constraint is most likely incorrect, can you update your question with the relevant sections?