# Weblogic 10.3: Webapp security using web.xml and DB roles inside WLS console

Tags: java, security, weblogic, container-managed

### Scenario

We are using Weblogic Server 10.3.4 to run our webapp which has security constraints enabled in order to require a user to sign in before he/she can use the application. The user and group information shall reside in the application database, the authentication shall be handled by WLS (the container).

I have set up a database schema as [described in this blog article](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/03/11/configuring-sql-authenticator-with-weblogic-server/), set up a new Security Realm "app.realm" in WLS console and defined a `SQLAuthenticator` inside it.

After having restarted WLS I can see my user and group definitons from the database in "app.realm" in the WLS web console. The user I am trying to authenticate is member of the `WEBAPP_USER` group (I see the group membership on the user's detail page in WLS console).

When I deploy the application (using standard settings, no adjustments in the WLS web console) and call a protected URL, I am redirected to the `login.html` form as expected. However, no matter what I try, entering the (right) password always yields authentication failure sending me to the `login_error.html` page. For debugging purposes, I have enabled plain text passwords in my `SQLAuthenticator`, so I am pretty sure having used proper credentials.

I already saw [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931119/configuring-container-managed-security-in-weblogic) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270643/weblogic-simple-realm-like-tomcat-users-xml) threads, but neither seems to help with my problem.

#### Update 1

Thanks to emzy's comment I now see that WLS is checking the credentials against the default realm "myrealm" and tries to resolve the login username against the embedded LDAP:

```
...
####<20.04.2011 09:29 Uhr MESZ> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <hostname> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1303284573150> <BEA-000000> <getDNForUser search("ou=people,ou=myrealm,dc=nvs_dev", "(&(uid=app.user)(objectclass=person))", base DN & below)>
####<20.04.2011 09:29 Uhr MESZ> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <hostname> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1303284573150> <BEA-000000> <DN for user app.user: null>
####<20.04.2011 09:29 Uhr MESZ> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <hostname> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1303284573150> <BEA-000000> <returnConnection conn:LDAPConnection { ldapVersion:2 bindDN:""}>
####<20.04.2011 09:29 Uhr MESZ> <Debug> <SecurityAtn> <hostname> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1303284573151> <BEA-000000> <javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090302]Authentication Failed: User app.user denied
        at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:229)
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ...
```

#### Update 2

I now performed these steps and get the authentication to work:

- Add the `SQLAuthenticator` to the default realm "myrealm" in WLS console
- Set both Weblogic's `DefaultAuthenticator` and the new `SQLAuthenticator` as `SUFFICIENT` in the respective provider settings (the "JAAS control flag" how they call it)
- Restart WLS

One questions remains, though:

### Questions

- <strike>Does WLS have some additional logging besides the standard log files in the `<domain>/server/AdminServer/logs` folder where I can see what happens?</strike>
- <strike>What am I doing wrong / What part in the puzzle am I missing to get my form-based authentication to work with my application?</strike>
- **Why does WLS use "myrealm" for authentication when I am giving "app.realm" explicitly in my `web.xml`?**

Here are my configuration details:

#### web.xml

```
...
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Webapp Platform</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>app-realm</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/login_error.html</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
  <description>Standard user</description>
  <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role> 
...
```

#### weblogic.xml

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  ...
  <security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <principal-name>WEBAPP_USER</principal-name>
  </security-role-assignment>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

#### login.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
<table>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="j_username"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="j_password"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=right><input type=submit value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your login.html page? Just the login form part of it should be enough. Also, are your users part of the WEBAPP_USER group in your security configuration? Past that, as emzy has suggested, if you enable debug for the weblogic/security/atn subsection of the debug tree, that will give you some fairly targeted information about what's happening with the login attempt.

Comment: @kevinpowe Thanks for your comment, I added the details above (login form and user membership) for clarification. Yes, the user is member of the group `WEBAPP_USER`.

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but I thought that I'd add this in case anyone else stumbles on this page like I did. 
The "realm" tag in the "login-config" is not what you think: "Note: The <realm-name> element does not refer to system security realms within WebLogic Server. This element defines the realm name to use in HTTP Basic authorization."
(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1019996)
That is, it's only used in conjunction with the <auth-method> being BASIC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the Server -> Debug tab on the console, you can enable debug/trace level logging. I would try enabling all of the security related logs to see if shows any warnings or exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

that's a tricky concept with the auth realms.
Regarding your last open question:
- Why does WLS use "myrealm" for authentication when I am giving "app.realm" explicitly in my web.xml?

You can configure multiple security realms in WebLogic, however only ONE can be active ( in this case the default myrealm). That is one of the annoying limitiations unofrtunately
Inactive ones are not used at all. Referencing an inactive realm in web.xml have no effect.

look here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/overview.htm#i1093279

Comment: That's correct response: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/overview.htm#SECMG117 ; cite:"You can configure multiple security realms in a domain; however, only one can be the active security realm." To complete this here is link to explain web.xml <realm-name> meaning: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/web_xml.htm#WBAPP557